# Problem with anchors in blend4web

Tags: blend4web

I have a question

I try to put a custom html object on an anchors for a empty object.

problem is when I try this on an bundled style project it works fine no problem
But in a non bundled external project as soon as I have a HTML element with the good ID the scene stop loading.
Any idea why? what am I missing here?

here is the code for the bundled project :

```
"use strict"

// register the application module
b4w.register("test", function(exports, require) {

// import modules used by the app
var m_app       = require("app");
var m_data      = require("data");

/**
 * export the method to initialize the app (called at the bottom of this file)
 */
exports.init = function() {
    m_app.init({
        canvas_container_id: "main_canvas_container",
        callback: init_cb,
        show_fps: true,
        console_verbose: true,
        autoresize: true
    });
}

/**
 * callback executed when the app is initialized 
 */
function init_cb(canvas_elem, success) {

    if (!success) {
        console.log("b4w init failure");
        return;
    }

    // ignore right-click on the canvas element
    canvas_elem.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    };

    load();
}

/**
 * load the scene data
 */
function load() {

        var torus_text = document.createElement("span");
    torus_text.id = "buttonPlay";
    torus_text.style.position = "absolute";
    torus_text.style.padding = "5px";
    torus_text.style.visibility = "hidden";
        var torus_img = document.createElement("img");
    torus_img.src = "Images/B_play.png";
    torus_img.atl = "the button";
    torus_img.height = "42";
    torus_img.width = "75";
    torus_text.appendChild(torus_img);

    document.body.appendChild(torus_text);

    m_data.load("test.json", load_cb);
}

/**
 * callback executed when the scene is loaded
 */
function load_cb(data_id) {
    m_app.enable_camera_controls();

    // place your code here

}


});

// import the app module and start the app by calling the init method
b4w.require("test").init();


and the one for the non bundled external project :
"use strict"


// register the application module
b4w.register("JumboConf", function(exports, require) {

// import modules used by the app
var m_app       = require("app");
var m_cfg       = require("config");
var m_data      = require("data");
var m_preloader = require("preloader");
var m_ver       = require("version");



// detect application mode
var DEBUG = (m_ver.type() == "DEBUG");

// automatically detect assets path
var APP_ASSETS_PATH = m_cfg.get_std_assets_path() + "JumboConf/";
```

and the one for the non bundled external project :

```
"use strict"


// register the application module
b4w.register("JumboConf", function(exports, require) {

// import modules used by the app
var m_app       = require("app");
var m_cfg       = require("config");
var m_data      = require("data");
var m_preloader = require("preloader");
var m_ver       = require("version");



// detect application mode
var DEBUG = (m_ver.type() == "DEBUG");

// automatically detect assets path
var APP_ASSETS_PATH = m_cfg.get_std_assets_path() + "JumboConf/";

/**
 * export the method to initialize the app (called at the bottom of this file)
 */
exports.init = function() {
    m_app.init({
        canvas_container_id: "main_canvas_container",
        callback: init_cb,
        show_fps: DEBUG,
        console_verbose: DEBUG,
        autoresize: true
    });
}

/**My function
*/
function CreateBt(id, source, hgt, wht, altern) {

    var btText = document.createElement("div");
        btText.id = id;
        btText.style.position = "absolute";
        btText.style.padding = "5px";
    btText.style.visibility = "hidden";
    var btImage = document.createElement("img");
    btImage.src = "/Images/"+source;
    btImage.atl = altern;
    btImage.height = hgt;
    btImage.width = wht;
    btText.appendChild(btImage);
    document.body.appendChild(btText);

}

function IdeCration(){
    CreateBt("RotBts","Bt_choix.png","42","72","bt_play.png");
}   


/**
 * callback executed when the app is initialized 
 */
function init_cb(canvas_elem, success) {

    if (!success) {
        console.log("b4w init failure");
        return;
    }

    m_preloader.create_preloader();

    // ignore right-click on the canvas element
    canvas_elem.oncontextmenu = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    };

    load();
}

/**
 * load the scene data
 */
function load() {
    IdeCration();
    m_data.load(APP_ASSETS_PATH + "JumboConf.json", load_cb, preloader_cb);

}

/**
 * update the app's preloader
 */
function preloader_cb(percentage) {
    m_preloader.update_preloader(percentage);
}

/**
 * callback executed when the scene data is loaded
 */
function load_cb(data_id, success) {

    if (!success) {
        console.log("b4w load failure");
        return;
    }

    m_app.enable_camera_controls();

    // place your code here

}


});

// import the app module and start the app by calling the init method
b4w.require("JumboConf").init();
```

Comment: hey, you might want to repeat your question on Blend4Web forums